# Middleware in firebase cloud function using onRequest never gets hit

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

Here is my simple cloud function(index.js):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors');
exports.myFn = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log("hit this");
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    // ...
    console.log("inside cors");
    res.send(200);
  });
});
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am using the middleware using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#use_middleware_modules_with) link to the docs.
But when this function is hit (using postman), I just get this:

[image]

And this seems to be happening with any other middleware. (I tested with multer too which I actually need).

PS: I also tried putting `return` before cors(as shown in docs.) but to same result.

**EDIT:**

I am simply calling this function using postman( POST https://us-central1-testprojectsofl.cloudfunctions.net/myFn ).

The github repo for the minimal project demonstrating this is located here: https://github.com/rahulserver/cfmiddlewaretest

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly how you are invoking this function.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue.  Please also show the **complete** code - you should be exporting this function somewhere in index.js.

Comment: The [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) needs to be copied into the question itself.  External links can go stale over time and become useless to others in the future.

Comment: @DougStevenson this is the only function in my whole project. All I can include is the package.json. Do you think that is even necessary?

Comment: Certainly you have requires or imports in index.js that completes your example?  Anyone should be able to copy the code into their own project to reproduce it problem.  Showing package.json definitely would not hurt, as it shows the versions of the libraries you're using.

Comment: I will also point out that cors requires two requests.  The first request is going to be a pre-flight request, and the second will be the actual request with additional information.  The first request is definitely not a normal request.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @DougStevenson added the full code including package.json. Even using multer gives the same error. Since the logs say "Hit this" was printed, that means its something related to middlewares in cloud functions and not specific to cors middleware.

Comment: Also posted on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require cors, try it like this:

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
```

This duplicates what you see in the official samples:

- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js
- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/big-ben/functions/index.js
- https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/username-password-auth/functions/index.js